# What is the maximum number of subnets I can get for either 10.0.0.0/8 or 100.64.0.0/16 with a max of about 10 hosts per subnet

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

What is the maximum number of subnets I can get of 10 hosts or so per subnet for 10.0.0.0/8 or 100.64.0.0/16.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: See [this excellent answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) for how to do this. You need to do IP manipulation in binary, then it becomes obvious, and doing it otherwise leads to errors.

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to figure out how many docker subnets with 10 containers each I can create on swarm. I have zero networking knowlege however. And this is probably a really ignorant question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `10.0.0.0/8`:

- Default Subnet is `255.0.0.0`
- 10 Hosts would round up to 16 (2^4)
- We have 24 bits to use, 4 bits for Host, so 20 bits for Networks
- 2^20 would give us **1048576 Networks**, with a Subnet of `255.255.255.240`
- This would result in `10.0.0.0/28`

For `100.64.0.0/16`:

- Default Subnet is `255.255.0.0`
- 10 Host would round up to 16 (2^4)
- We have 16 bits to use, 4 bits for Host, so 12 bits for Networks
- 2^12 would give us **4096 Networks**, with a Subnet of `255.255.255.240`
- This would result in `100.64.0.0/28`

Comment: 255.255.255.128 is /25, not /28.

Comment: @grawity Whoops, my bad. Typo in the subnet. Should be fixed now.

Comment: (Also you have a typo in the network itself – OP specified [100.64.0.0](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6598).)